# What is the meaning of " such as" in this text?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

No difficulties had delayed the invaders but such as Nature had interposed to thwart them.

Comment: "...but (those) such as nature had interposed..."

Comment: It’s really just “such”, but you can replace the two words with the word “whatever“ to get a sense of its meaning.

Comment: It's a somewhat archaic construction.

Answer (score 1):

"Such" refers to a *type* of something previously mentioned, for example:

> -Have you experienced any difficulties of nature?
>   -I have experienecd no such difficulties.

"But" introduces an *exception* or a contrasting clause to what has already been mentioned. So, your sentence essentially means that no difficulties had delayed the invaders *except the kind caused by nature*.

Answer (score 0):

*Such* is a fused-head construction in this sentence (the understood head of the noun phrase being *difficulties*). The prepositional phrase headed by *as* contains a comparative clause and modifies *such*.

**such** difficulties -> difficulties as **Nature had interposed (difficulties)**

> No difficulties had delayed the invaders but **such** (difficulties) **as**
>   Nature had interposed to thwart them.

This construction is very similar to a relative :

> ...but **those which** Nature had interposed to thwart them

There is no difference between the interpretation of the original and that with the relative constructions substituted. This use of *such as* is rare, definitely formal and probably bordering on archaic.

> Then, going a few steps forward, he would pause at a heap, and begin
>   counting cinders into his basket, as though it had been so much solid
>   coin . **Such as** knew the broker heaved a sigh of compassion. (The Career of Puffer Hopkins; Mathews, Cornelius; 1842)

relative: *Those who*

> No refuse or worked objects of any kind were found in this black
>   earth, except in the recess in the east wall, as described, and in the
>   upper portion immediately under the ashes . **Such as** existed
>   outside the recess may have become mixed in the same way; that is, by
>   being thrown on the top as it existed at the moment and being later
>   covered by the water; or it may have worked in from the ashes above. 
>   (Archeological Investigations, Bureau of American Ethnology, Bulletin 76, 1922)

relative: *Those which*