# What does Merriam-Webster mean by "being such in practice or effect"?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I was looking at the definition of "practical" and found a phrase  that I couldn't understand.

The phrase that I'm talking about is

> [being such in practice or effect](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practical)

And also, according to the information on the same page, this definition of "practical" is a synonym of the word "virtual". But I couldn't any definition of "virtual" that is same as the definition of "practical" that I was talking about earlier.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the M-W definition is misquoted. It's *being such in practice **or** effect*, not ***of*** (i.e. *being "practical", either in practice or in effect*). That's to say, either ***virtually*** or ***effectively*** "practical".

Comment: Sorry, I misquoted the original sentence. But still, I don't understand the sentence that I've mentioned.

Comment: Can you give the full context of that phrase? It may make sense to explain in the full sentence. Also, how is 'practical' a synonym of 'virti ual' (sp?)? They might overlap in some extreme vagueness but on the surface not at all.

Comment: @Mitch That is the full phrase.

Comment: I don/t get it. give a link to the original so I can see what you're seeing. Are you saying it is something like "practical (adv) - being such in practice or effect"? Also, the title says 'of' - which is it?

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practical Here's the link

Comment: This is an interesting question, but you need to make it easier for us. Edit your question to add the link and give more of the text of M-W. Also, expand your question with what is at 'virtual'. (I think you have found a poor entry by M-W, for both 'practical' and 'virtual': 'practically' and 'virtually' can be synonymous - "Because I just graduated highschool, I am practically/virtually an adult" (the adverb means something like "for all intents and purposes", but the first def of 'practical' is 'nontheoretical', and 'virtual' is 'unreal'.

Comment: @Mitch: *This question is **practically / virtually / effectively** General Reference*. And for the OP, as implied by my first comment, the words ***being such*** in M-W's definition carry exactly the same meaning as ***being practical***.

Comment: In the definition you gave here, there is no obvious prior referent for he pronoun 'such' (in the definition for practical or virtual), so it is very vague.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No it's not genref. The OP is asking -about- the definitions and what sense can be made of them. The M-W definitions are unclear (and teasing out the difference of two words is very much on topic).

Comment: @Mitch:  The "obvious" referent for "such" is the word ***practical*** itself.

Comment: There was the earlier question [What is the meaning of “ such as” in this text?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/535913/) here on ELU, where it might not be *quite* so easy to see that "such" references preceding "difficulties". But to a first approximation I think such questions should be asked on English Language **Learners**, not here.

Comment: "such" presumably refers to the previous definition (1a), as the quote is numbered 1b. M-W uses this formula a lot where one meaning expands on another.

Comment: We need context. I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

The *such* refers to the noun that *practical* modifies. The word *such* here cannot be referring to a previous definition, because in the definition of *virtual*, a very similar definition appears as the first definition of the word.

One definition of [*practical*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practical) in Merriam-Webster is:

> 1 b: being such in practice or effect : VIRTUAL
> a practical failure.

So, calling something *a practical failure* would mean that it was a failure in practice (although maybe it was a success in theory or in trial uses).

The same use of *such* appears in their definition of [*virtual*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtual):

> 1: being such in essence or effect though not formally recognized or admitted
> a virtual dictator

So *a virtual dictator* is somebody who is effectively a dictator, even though they do not admit they are one.

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated because it involves how words work, how dictionaries work, and how M-W works.

Yes, that phrase all by itself is strange and difficult to parse (if at all). The entire (relevant definition is:

```
1a: of, relating to, or manifested in practice or action : not theoretical or ideal
   // _a practical question_
   // _for all practical purposes_
 b: _being such in practice or effect_ : VIRTUAL
   // _a practical failure_
```

As noted in a comment here, 'such' is a pronoun here that M-W uses often to refer to a previous definition, in this instance 1a. Even so, replacing the pronoun with its (simplified) referent, 'being *of practice or action* in practice or effect' being so tautologous almost washes away any meaning it had to start with. And frankly, the example doesn't help me distinguish the two submeanings.

So I have a very hard time trying to figure out what *M-W* means with this definition.

I'm no lexicographer so I can only explain what I think the primary meaning, 1a, of 'practical' is - it is opposed to abstract or thinking too far in advance, it means just getting things done now with what's available (as you can see this is not a good dictionary definition but I think it suffices for getting the idea across.

As to definition 1b, that it cites 'virtual' as a synonym is interesting because, well, let's look at M-W's definition there:

```
1: being such in essence or effect though not formally recognized or admitted
  // _a virtual dictator_
...
4: of, relating to, or being a hypothetical particle whose existence is inferred from indirect evidence
  // _virtual photons_
```

With my own prejudices about 'virtual', this seems quite at odds with the definition of 'practical'. It's not exactly an antonym, but seems correlated with those ideas.

However, abstract words can be a little bit mushy. I can attempt a possible hint as to why the individual lexicographer connected  'virtual' with 'practical'. Via semantic drifting of the adverbial forms, ['practically'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/practically) and ['virtually'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/virtually) both have changed little by little over the years to converge to mean 'almost'.

> The actor had appeared in so few films lately that they had become *practically*/*virtually* unknown.

Despite the same root, this doesn't make 'practical and 'virtual' synonymous though.

Comment: Yes; 'It's a practical failure' could be used for 'To all intents and purposes, it's a failure, although I wouldn't because of the ambiguity. It would be used in say 'OK, it's passed the  Backhander-Vested utility test, but all that means is that we need a better test.'